# Popup tweet box and closing it after clicking tweet

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a popup tweet box on my page to share the site. I am using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fbs_click() {
    var twtTitle = document.title;
    var twtUrl = location.href;
    var maxLength = 140 - (twtUrl.length + 1);
    if (twtTitle.length > maxLength) {
        twtTitle = twtTitle.substr(0, (maxLength - 3)) + '...';
    }
    var twtLink = 'https://twitter.com/home?status=go%20to%20this%20site!';
    var x = screen.width/2 - 520/2; 
    var y = screen.height/2 - 350/2-100; 
    window.open(twtLink, '','height=350,width=520,left='+x+',top='+y);
}
</script>
```

With this in the html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="fbs_click();" ><img class="right" src="twitter.png">
```

This all works well however when I click tweet the window will remain open and then go to the twitter homepage. Is there anyway to get this window to close after clicking tweet?

Answer (score 0):

If you save it to a variable like:

```
var win = window.open( ...
```

You can close it with

```
win.close();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close

As for where to put this, check out Twitter's [Web Intent](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events) events:

```
twttr.events.bind(
    'tweet',
    function (event) {
        // Do something there
    }
);
```

Comment: Do I need to assign the win.close() to the tweet button? Not sure how to do that because the page is generated dynamically.